# ggplot - geom_segment() with mutiple arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on Principal Component Analysis (PCA).
I found `ggfortify` works great but would like to do some manual adjustments.

Here then trying to plot the PCA results as below:

```
evec <- read.table(textConnection("
  PC1        PC2        PC3
  -0.5708394 -0.6158420 -0.5430295
  -0.6210178 -0.1087985  0.7762086
  -0.5371026  0.7803214 -0.3203424"
), header = TRUE, row.names = c("M1", "M2", "M3"))

res.ct <- read.table(textConnection("
  PC1        PC2        PC3
  -1.762697 -1.3404825 -0.3098503
  -2.349978 -0.0531175  0.6890453
  -1.074205  1.5606429 -0.6406848
  2.887080 -0.7272039 -0.3687029
  2.299799  0.5601610  0.6301927"
), header = TRUE, row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
gpobj <- 
  res.ct %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
  geom_point(color="grey30") +
  annotate(geom="text", x=res.ct$PC1*1.07, y=res.ct$PC2*1.07,
           label=rownames(res.ct))

for (i in 1:nrow(evec))
{
  PCx <- evec[i,1]
  PCy <- evec[i,2]
  axisname <- rownames(evec)[[i]]
  gpobj <- gpobj +
    geom_segment(
      data = evec[i,],
      aes(
        x = 0, y = 0,
        xend = PC1, yend = PC2
        # xend = PCx, yend = PCy  #not work as intended
      ),
      arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, "mm")),
      color = "red"
    ) +
    annotate(
      geom = "text",
      x = PCx * 1.15, y = PCy * 1.15,
      label = axisname,
      color = "red"
    )
}
gpobj
```

The code works well but when I tried to use the commented line `xend = PCx, yend = PCy` instead of `xend = PC1, yend = PC2`, it does not work well as I intended, it does not show the all arrows.

`xend = PC1, yend = PC2` works well:

[image: <code>xend = PC1, yend = PC2</code> works well]

`xend = PCx, yend = PCy` does not:

[image: <code>xend = PCx, yend = PCy</code> does not]

Question: 
Why does not `geom_segment()` maintain the previous arrow when the starting and ending points are specified by environment variables rather than referred by variable names from `data =`?

Comment: Which ggplot2 version are you using? Seems to yield the same result for 3.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you used, when `PCx` / `PCy` are specified inside the aesthetic mapping `aes(...)` (as opposed to hard coding them to fixed aesthetic values outside `aes(...)`, as done for the `annotate` layers), the actual values are only evaluated when you plot / print the ggplot object `gpobj`.

This means the values of `PCx` / `PCy` are evaluated **outside** the for-loop. By this point, they correspond to the last values they took on, for `i = 3`, and that is why only one arrow segment (actually three arrows overlaid atop one another) is visible. Moving `xend = PCx, yend = PCy` outside `aes(...)` should achieve the look you want.

I do wonder why you choose to use for-loops in the first place, though. Wouldn't something like the following serve the same purpose?

```
# convert row names to explicit columns
res.ct <- tibble::rownames_to_column(res.ct)
evec <- tibble::rownames_to_column(evec)

# plot
res.ct %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
  geom_point(color="grey30") +
  geom_text(aes(x = PC1 * 1.07, y = PC2 * 1.07,
                label = rowname)) +
  geom_segment(data = evec,
               aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2, group = rowname),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, "mm")),
               color = "red") +
  geom_text(data = evec,
            aes(x = PC1 * 1.15, y = PC2 * 1.15, label = rowname),
            colour = "red")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. I didn't realized when the aesthetics variables are evaluated. Your example gave me a better understanding for ggplot2. (using ggplot2 version 3.1.1)